# Displaying a Video in Wistia using jxbrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I am trying to display a movie that I am hosting on Wista in a com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser in Eclipse with SWT.

The movie in Wistia has its own controls.  This is the URL:

https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/lpvu51xcig#?fullscreenButton

The movie displays fine if the above is typed in a normal web page.  If I run it through:

```
_browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
_browserView = new BrowserView(_browser);
_canvas.setScene(new Scene(_browserView));
```

And then bring it up in SWT, I lose the lower movie controls and then when I click on the movie, itthen pops up a Save dialog and tries to save out this file name:  78d1a41ef6ea7d38a69c0753b60c3f492c2737f7.bin

Any help or ideas would help.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It seems that video you are trying to play was encoded with proprietary codecs. JxBrowser does not support proprietary codecs by default. How to obtain build with codecs you can find using the following link: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013050-mp3-mp4-h-264